# How to find the normal of the intersection of 2 vectors on a plane.

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, plane-geometry

I am wondering how I would go about finding the normal of plane when I don't know the equation of said plane. I am drawing a cube so I have the corner points of a square, and I need to find the the normal of the center point of this square. I am assuming that I use the diagonal corner points to find the center point and then find the normal from there, but everywhere I have looked and google are only offering me solutions that require the equation of the plane, which I don't have.

I am not sure if I am explaining myself correctly, so I will edit the question to reflect the responses to make it more generalised if I need to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The normal to *which* plane?

Comment: @travis I have the 4 corner points of a square, and I need the normal from the center of this square.

Comment: Any vector $\bf N$ normal to the square $\bf ABCD$ is in particular normal to both of its diagonals, which we can identify with the vectors ${\bf C} - {\bf A}$ and ${\bf D} - {\bf B}$, and hence is some multiple of the cross product $({\bf C} - {\bf A}) \times ({\bf D} - {\bf B})$ (which is nonzero because the diagonals of the square are not parallel).

Comment: @travis So I need to find the center point using the diagonals, and then find the cross product of the new vectors going from the centerpoint to the corners?

Comment: If you just want to find a normal vector, you needn't even find the center of the square. If you want to find a parameterization of the normal line, you can find the center of the square, which is, e.g., ${\bf O} := \frac{1}{2}({\bf A} + {\bf C})$ and form the parameterized line ${\bf r}(t) := {\bf O} + t {\bf N}$, where $\bf N$ is any vector normal to the plane; by the above, we can just take $\bf N$ to be the cross product in my previous comment (which in particular doesn't involve the center of the square).